# Query on local datastore with unsaved pinned object of id null in Parse SDK Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-room, parse-server, parse-android-sdk

I'm using Parse sdk for android.

In offline mode,
I created some parse objects and pinned them using

```
  ...
  ParseObject.pinAll(cartItems)
  orderObject.pin()       //orderObject.objectId() returns null!
  ...
```

Later when i query cartItems in localDatastore i  use

```
    ...
    query.whereEqualTo("order", orderObject);
    query.fromLocalDatastore().ignoreACLs();
    ...
```

**but the query gives no result,probably because objectId of orderObject is null.**

> Is there any way to execute this query successfully?

If parse is incapable to do this should i go for **Room database** to store the data offline or is there any better alternative?

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

There are two subclasses

```
Order extends ParseObject 
OrderIte extends ParseObject
```

I create some OrderItem-s and one order.
I put Order pointer in OrderItem-s
and pin them all.

Later when i query OrderItem class in local datastore
I want to retrieve OrdeItem-s for a perticular order.
So in the OrderItem query i set

```
query.equaTo("order",myOrder.getObjectId())
```

But since the device is offline the whole time 
`myOrder.getObjectId()` returns null and the query fails to find the orderItems for
myOrder

```
Expected query -> Select all from OrderItem where order = myOrder.getObjectId()
Actual query parse makes -> Select all from OrderItem where order = null
```

null as the object is stored offline in localdatastore.

[ParseObject pinInBackground returning null objectId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25289755/parseobject-pininbackground-returning-null-objectid)

This makes basic queries fail and makes the LocalDatastore less useful.

Comment: What is the class that you are trying to query? How does it relate to order? Have you also pinned the objects of this class?

Comment: Question updated.Please check again

Comment: Have you tried `query.equaTo("order",myOrder)` instead of `query.equaTo("order",myOrder.getObjectId())`? It should be the right way as you can see in the first example of [this](https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#relational-queries) link.

Comment: Code might differ a bit.But i did as per documentation.I'm sure there's no mistake in code. It lies in objectId giving null for Offline object

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat working solution for me is:

when setting pointer of Order in OrderItem-s

instead of

```
orderItem.put("order",myOrderObject)
```

i use

```
String randomId = generateRandomString()
myOrderObject.put("temp_orderOfflineId",randomId)
orderItem.put("order_id",randomId )
```

and in query
instead of

```
orderItemquery.equaTo("order",myOrder.getObjectId())
```

i use

```
query.equaTo("order_id",myOrder.getString("temp_orderOfflineId"))
```

I use this approach 
This later makes sync with server hard,very hard.

Waiting for better solution